# Call require API 26 (current min 21):getHeader

Tags: httprequest, retrofit2, android-mvp

> I am facing issue"Call require API 26 (current min 21):getHeader" when i am using MVP architecture where getHeader required API above 26 level but i want it should be work on all devices in else condition.
>   using retrofit with MVP 
>   code in below

```
@Override
public void init() {
        contactUsView.showLoadingLayout();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mainInteractor = new ContactUsPresenter(getHeader(), getBody());
        }
        mainInteractor.loadItems(this);
}
```